Spock mocking for exception causing code coverage issue
I have below code which I am trying to tests for in Spock
Class Validator{
    String envCheck(String environment) {
        if (environment == null || environment.isEmpty()) {
            new CustomException(steps).errorThrowException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY OR NULL")
        }
        environment = (environment.equalsIgnoreCase('Test')) ? 'UAT' : environment
       return environment
    }
    
}

class ValidatorTest extends Specification {
    def "validateEnvironment"() {
        given:
        Validator val = new Validator()
        CustomException mockException = GroovyMock(class: 'CustomException', global: true)
        when:
        envCheck(null)
        then:
        1 * new CustomException(*_) >> mockException
        1 * mockException.errorThrowException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY OR NULL")>>{ throw new IllegalStateException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY OR NULL") }
        thrown(IllegalStateException)
    }
}

Class CustomException {
    Object steps

    CustomException(final Object steps){
        this.steps = steps
    }

    void errorThrowException(String error) {
        printError(error)
        throw new IllegalStateException(error)
    }

    void printError(String error){
            this.steps.ansiColor('xterm') {
            this.steps.echo("""\033[3mERROR: $error \033[0m""")
        }
    }

}

When I run this test it executes fine but in jacoco coverage report says the if condition not covered . When i change the code to directly throw exception "throw new IllegalStateException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY")"
and remove mocking in tests and just use thrown in test , jacoco coverage is shown covered and is GREEN. How do I fix this. CustomException.errorThrowException throws IllegalStateException internally. but when mocked code coverage is not coming properly.

Please, be polite enough to either accept and upvote my answer or comment on it, if anything is unclear or wrong about it. Thank you.

It is not helpful to post pseudo code that does not even compile, e.g. Class with upper-case "C" instead of class. Furthermore, in class Validator you use new CustomException(steps), but steps is undefined at that point.
Furthermore, you cannot just call envCheck(null), it should be val.envCheck(null). The class parameter for the Groovy Mock is also unnecessary here.
If I fix those issues, the test passes. Before, it failed.
Here is my MCVE:
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78861028

class Validator {
  String envCheck(String environment) {
    if (environment == null || environment.isEmpty())
      new CustomException("XXX").errorThrowException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY OR NULL")
    environment = (environment.equalsIgnoreCase('Test')) ? 'UAT' : environment
    return environment
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78861028

class CustomException {
  Object steps

  CustomException(final Object steps) {
    this.steps = steps
  }

  void errorThrowException(String error) {
    printError(error)
    throw new IllegalStateException(error)
  }

  void printError(String error) {
    this.steps.ansiColor('xterm') {
      this.steps.echo("""\033[3mERROR: $error \033[0m""")
    }
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78861028

import spock.lang.Specification

class ValidatorTest extends Specification {
  def "validateEnvironment"() {
    given:
    Validator validator = new Validator()
    CustomException customException = GroovyMock(global: true)

    when:
    validator.envCheck(null)

    then:
    1 * new CustomException(*_) >> customException
    1 * customException.errorThrowException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY OR NULL") >> { throw new IllegalStateException("ENVIRONMENT CANNOT BE EMPTY OR NULL") }
    thrown(IllegalStateException)
  }
}

Try it in the Groovy Web Console.

Update: As for coverage, it looks fine here in IntelliJ IDEA (I did not bother to set up Jacoco):

Of course, the if condition is only partly covered, because your test does not match with environment.isEmpty(), only with environment == null.

Please note my update concerning coverage.
